# Controlling Smart Home Devices from Android TV

Tags: actions-on-google, android-tv, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I am working on Google Assistant integration for Smart Devices.

Apart from Tablets and Cell phones, I want to control smart home devices via Android TVs. I looked at the Google Docs (https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview), I had no difficulties with Google Local Home SDK, OAuth 2 installation.

But there is this;

In the link https://www.android.com/tv/, "control home devices" tab and;

At https://assistant.google.com/platforms/tv/ there is a "control smart home" tab.

In other words, the control of smart devices can be done from Android TVs.

But; It says on the https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview page that all smart home integration processes will start through the Google Home application. At least, even if this application is not installed, the first process can start from the add device tab in the google assistant settings.

But I couldn't find a google home app for Android TV on google play.

When I say "turn off the lights" to my TV, it says "no such device, open assistant settings". There are assistant settings. But not like cell phones. None of the android tvs have an assistant settings with "add device" option.

So then;

https://www.android.com/tv/
https://assistant.google.com/platforms/tv/

as shown in the links; With which integration can we control smart home devices? As shown in these links; How can they control devices at home using google assistant with Android TVs?

Anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Google Home App is available only on the phone. In your use case a user needs Google Home App on the phone to **set up** a device and then Google Assistant on Android TV can **control** the device. Keep in mind that to have the same google account on the phone and the android TV for this flow to work.